# How to write in /etc/profile using bash | Permission Denied

Tags: bash, ubuntu, permissions, environment

I'm creating a bash script to set up an Ubuntu 16.04 lts OS to download, install and other stuff without introduce each command separately and I have to write in the /etc/profile file to add a PATH environment variable. When my code get into that line it appears the Permission Denied message, this is what I have:

```
sudo echo "export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin" >> /etc/profile
bash: /etc/profile: Permission denied
```

Do you know how could I solve this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Shell i/o redirection happens *before* the shell executes your command...in other words, when you write:

```
sudo somecommand >> /etc/profile
```

The `>> /etc/profile` part is performed as the current user, not as `root`.  That's why you're getting the "permission denied" message.  There are various ways of solving this.  You can run:

```
sudo sh -c "echo export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin >> /etc/profile"
```

Or you can take advantage of the append (`-a`) flag to the `tee` command:

```
echo "export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin" | sudo tee -a /etc/profile
```

Comment: There's another problem here -- since `$PATH` is in double-quotes, it'll be substituted by the current shell, not stored literally in the profile. It needs to be either in single-quotes or escaped (and if you use the `sh -c` option, it needs to be protected by *two* layers of quotes/escapes).

Comment: That's pretty awesome!! THANK YOU!!

Comment: is `export` needed? I'm ending up with the word "export" in `/etc/profile`

Comment: I mean...of course you are. That's what these instructions do. The `export` command exports a variable to the environment; without that, you're just setting a shell variable that won't be inherited by child processes.

Comment: `sudo sh -c "echo 'export PATH=\$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin' >> /etc/profile"` is better

Answer (score 1):

```sh
sudo sh -c "echo MY_GLOBAL_ENV_TO_MY_CURRENT_DIR=$(pwd)" >> /etc/environment"
```